# Office 365 trial account

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need help on my newly created account. I can't add a free trial subscription on my account.

I have been trying to use the free trial version of Office 365 Enterprise E3 but each time I try to add the trial subscription, I get this error message:

> Sorry, we can't process your request.
>
> The verification checks on your
>   payment method have failed. Please select another payment method and
>   try again. If the problem doesn't go away, please submit a service
>   request. Closesupport informationImage correlation id:
>   eas#da509161-a249-4edd-9d22-ea1fc95c1a46 error code: 0

Please can someone help me out on this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this community can exactly support you on your problem. As the error message states, there has been a problem with applying the payment method of your choice. You should ask support from Microsoft's O365 Support, as they are responsible of their service.

There has been a similar issue reported here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_dep365/the-verification-checks-on-your-payment-method/60d644bb-3393-40b6-80a9-883ec09e54da